# How to list tables in schema using R and dplyr.snowflakedb

Tags: r, dplyr, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can create a connection to the database using the following code block:

```
library("RJDBC", "DBI")
library("dplyr.snowflakedb")
library("dplyr")

options(dplyr.jdbc.classpath = "/jar_files/snowflake-jdbc-3.10.0.jar")

conn <- src_snowflakedb(
  user = "username",
  password = "password",
  account = "account",
  host = "account.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
  opts = list(
              warehouse = "PUBLIC",
              db = "PROD",
              schema = "SCHEMA")
)
```

When I run:

```
class(conn)
```

I get:

> class(conn)
> [1] "src_snowflakedb" "src_sql"         "src"

and if I run

```
db_list_tables(conn$con)
```

The result is:

> db_list_tables(conn$con)
> [1] "GA_CUSTOMER_CDP_TP"              "APPLICABLE_ROLES"                "COLUMNS"                         "DATABASES"
> [5] "ENABLED_ROLES"                   "EXTERNAL_TABLES"                 "FILE_FORMATS"                    "FUNCTIONS"
> [9] "INFORMATION_SCHEMA_CATALOG_NAME" "LOAD_HISTORY"                    "OBJECT_PRIVILEGES"               "PIPES"
> [13] "PROCEDURES"                      "REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS"         "REPLICATION_DATABASES"           "SCHEMATA"
> [17] "SEQUENCES"                       "STAGES"                          "TABLES"                          "TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"
> [21] "TABLE_PRIVILEGES"                "TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS"           "USAGE_PRIVILEGES"                "VIEWS"
> [25] "APPLICABLE_ROLES"                "COLUMNS"                         "DATABASES"                       "ENABLED_ROLES"
> [29] "EXTERNAL_TABLES"                 "FILE_FORMATS"                    "FUNCTIONS"                       "INFORMATION_SCHEMA_CATALOG_NAME"
> [33] "LOAD_HISTORY"                    "OBJECT_PRIVILEGES"               "PIPES"                           "PROCEDURES"
> [37] "REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS"         "REPLICATION_DATABASES"           "SCHEMATA"                        "SEQUENCES"
> [41] "STAGES"                          "TABLES"                          "TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"               "TABLE_PRIVILEGES"
> [45] "TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS"           "USAGE_PRIVILEGES"                "VIEWS"

How do I list the actual tables in the schema i.e product, sales, customer e.t.c?

Comment: have you already looked at this https://www.snowflake.com/blog/integrating-the-snowflake-data-warehouse-with-r-via-dplyr/

Answer (score 5):

While I am not familiar with snowflakedb, I recommend you try the `dbListTables` command in the `DBI` package:

```r
dbListTables(connection)
```

However this will not let you restrict to a specific schema, nor will it return schema names. For this, I recommend you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720911/list-tables-within-a-postgres-schema-using-r) where they use DBI to execute a database query that returns tables names:

```r
answer = dbGetQuery(connection, "string_that_is_database_code_for_fetching_table_names")
```

This approach should adapt easily to snowflakedb.